# Separate filter and sorting button for react table

Tags: reactjs, filtering, react-table, columnsorting

I want to create a separate button for each column in react table, to sort as well as to filter similar to the picture given below.
[image]

I'm able to make the button work, but every single time I'm trying to click on the button, the column is getting sorted.

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-eyrsol?)

- If I'm removing `column.getSortByToggleProps()` then the `onClick()` event is not working on the button.
- I'm not able to make the sorting happen even on clicking on the **ASCENDING** button using
  `sortBy(id, false, false)`, it's throwing errors.

What I want it to do.

- When you click on the filter icon the column shouldn't get sorted.
- It should sort the columns when you click the buttons in the component, not on the header title.
- When you select one checkbox from the filter the component should stay open.

Comment: Can you create codesandbox?

Comment: @Nemanja I've added a codesandbox and have explained the question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table instance property `setSortBy()` that can be used to set sorting programatically.

You can set a sort by passing it an array of objects to combine multiple sorts:

```js
setSortBy([{id: column.id, desc: false}])
```

[https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy#instance-properties:~:text=setSortBy](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy#instance-properties:%7E:text=setSortBy)

Comment: how would you call this I am trying to remove the default behavior of sort and have it be triggered on a button click